# How to re-enable hibernate in Kubuntu 11.10?

Tags: swap, hibernate

After making some changes to my swap space, namely deleting and recreating swap space, my Kubuntu 11.10 has lost hibernate functionality.  Although the button has returned, hibernating only appears to be working superficially until you try to resume the system - but instead of resuming you find it is restarting.

`swapon -s`:

```
    Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
    /dev/sda5                               partition       10237948        0       -1
```

Partitions:

[image]

/etc/fstab:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=0b109499-4feb-4ec1-b368-c7f945194e44 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
#/dev/sda5 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/sda5 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you missed this?

"Making the swap partition work for hibernate (optional)", third subsection [in this Ubuntu community help site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#line-84).  I think it's just what you need, telling the `resume` part of `initramfs` where swap is (via GRUB).

Comment: Thank you - the solution was contained in the subsection you referred me too - I needed to add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=UUID=...` in `/etc/default/grub`  and update `UUID`number in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`.

Comment: You may already know this, but as a hobbyist web developer myself, I couldn't resist noting that you can link the exact section by right-click,view source, identifying the identifier `id=...` and appending the relevant #id to the link (if it exists).  I have edited your link to reflect this, try it and see!  You should find well-written online documentation should contain ids for every section, and in the case of Ubuntu documentation ids are included for every line, which is exceptional and convenient if you want to cite to the line.

Comment: @ptrcao Or make your browser show the anchors: http://superuser.com/questions/192980/plugin-to-show-anchors-in-an-html-page

Comment: @Gilles Thanks, I didn't know that!  Could be useful.

Comment: @ptrcao, @Gilles: Thanks for your hints! `:)`